# how to get data from api after click button

Tags: api, react-native

I try to get data from api in react native. I using fetch.
my constructor :

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
   firstName: "",
   lastName:"",
   loading: true,
   dataSource:[],
  };
}
```

getting data with fetch but does not work:

```
componentDidMount(){
fetch("http://myurl.com/api/person?name="+this.state.firstName+"&last_name="+this.state.lastName)
.then(response => response.json())
.then((responseJson)=> {
  this.setState({
   loading: false,
   dataSource: responseJson.data
  })
})
.catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

also I have 2 text input for first/last name and one button and I want to get data from api after button click now I using setState

```
  <Item stackedLabel>
    <Label>First Name</Label>
    <Input name="firstName" onChangeText={(firstName)=>{this.setState({firstName: firstName});}} />
  </Item>
  <Item stackedLabel Last>
    <Label>Last Name</Label>
    <Input name="lastName" onChangeText={(lastName)=>{this.setState({lastName: lastName});}} />
  </Item>
  <Button style={styles.SearchButton} full><Text> Search Person </Text>
```

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more. What you actually want ?

Comment: when I write first and last name in input field and click search button I want to get data with this first and last name from api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On pressing Search button, call method that will be fetching data from api and remove the api call code from componentDidMount.

```
_onPressButton() {
    fetch("http://myurl.com/api/person?name="+this.state.firstName+"&last_name="+this.state.lastName)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
      this.setState({
       loading: false,
       dataSource: responseJson.data
      })
    })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
  }

<Button style={styles.SearchButton} onPress={() => this._onPressButton() } full><Text> Search Person </Text>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: when I tried onPress={this._onPressButton} nothing shows but when I trying onPress={this._onPressButton() } every time in loop

Comment: You are not binding _onPressButton to this, therefore the issue. You could use arrow function like `onPress={() => this._onPressButton() }` to solve this issue.